# how to make background transparent in threejs and PyQt app?

Tags: python, three.js, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using threejs to show some 3D objects in my PyQt application. After a little searching, I was able to display a cube. What I want to do is remove the background from the scene, that is, make it transparent so that we can see the blue color that is set as the background color for the app. I have no idea how I should do this. Please help.

main.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys

class QtSchemeHandler(QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler):
    def requestStarted(self, job):
        request_url = job.requestUrl()
        request_path = request_url.path()
        file = QFile('.' + request_path)
        file.setParent(job)
        job.destroyed.connect(file.deleteLater)
        file_info = QFileInfo(file)
        mime_database = QMimeDatabase()
        mime_type = mime_database.mimeTypeForFile(file_info)
        job.reply(mime_type.name().encode(), file)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue;')
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.scheme_handler = QtSchemeHandler()
        self.browser.page().profile().installUrlSchemeHandler(
            b"qt", self.scheme_handler
        )
        url = QUrl("qt://main")
        url.setPath("/index.html")
        self.browser.load(url)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.show)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheme = QWebEngineUrlScheme(b"qt")
    scheme.setFlags(QWebEngineUrlScheme.CorsEnabled)
    QWebEngineUrlScheme.registerScheme(scheme)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Three js earth</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js" integrity="sha512-dLxUelApnYxpLt6K2iomGngnHO83iUvZytA3YjDUCjT0HDOHKXnVYdf3hU4JjM8uEhxf9nD1/ey98U3t2vZ0qQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="module">
        
        const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl');

        // scene setup
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // camera setup
        const fov = 60;
        const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        const near = 0.1;
        const far = 10;
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 3)
        scene.add(camera);
 
        // renderer setup
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});

        // 3D Object
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);

        // point light
        const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1)
        pointLight.position.set(0, 0, 5);
        scene.add(pointLight);

        // handling resizing
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            render();
        }, false);

        // main loop
        function render(time) {
            cube.rotation.x -= 0.005;
            cube.rotation.y -= 0.005;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
        render();

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i would start with looking into layers / z-index with css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index make the html layer 0 and your three js canvas layer -1 ( i think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set the `QWebEngineView`'s `page` to have a transparent background.

In `main.py`:

```python
    ...
    self.scheme_handler = QtSchemeHandler()
+++ self.browser.page().setBackgroundColor(Qt.GlobalColor.transparent)      
    self.browser.page().profile().installUrlSchemeHandler(
      b"qt", self.scheme_handler
    )
    ...
```

Then, set the HTML page's background to transparent.

In `index.html`:

```html
    ...
    <style>
      body{
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
+++     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      }
    </style>
    ...
```

And finally, set the Three.js `WebGLRenderer` to use a transparent background.

Still in `index.html`:

```js
    // renderer setup
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: canvas, 
      antialias: true, 
+++   alpha: true
    });
```

[image: Screenshot showing transparent background]